# Reading data from the GPU asynchronously with Pixel Buffer Objects

Tags: opengl, buffer-objects

Getting data from the GPU seems to be a very slow task if you want to read it synchronized with the rest of your application. One possibility is to read *asynchronously* with the help of Pixel Buffer Objects. Unfortunately, I am not able to see how this is done.

First, I create a Pixel Buffer Object:

```
glGenBuffers(1, &pbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, pbo);
glBufferData(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, pbo_size, 0, GL_DYNAMIC_READ);
glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, 0);
```

Then I want to read pixels from a Frame Buffer Object:

```
glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, pbo);
glReadPixels(0, 0, w, h, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, 0);
GLfloat *ptr = glMapBufferRange(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, 0, pbo_size, GL_MAP_READ_BIT);
memcpy(pixels, ptr, pbo_size);
glUnmapBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER);
glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, 0);
```

But how is this asynchronous? Is glReadPixels or glMapBufferRange blocking the application until the GPU is 'ready'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `glReadPixels` call should start the copy to a cpu-visible buffer. (whenever it gets submitted to the GPU. You can force the submission with `glFlush`). You're starting the read asynchronously.

`glMapBufferRange` will force the `glReadPixels` call to finish if it wasn't (since you're now accessing the pointer on the CPU, there's no way around that).

So... don't do the 2 back-to-back, but rather significantly later.

Comment: Is there a possibility to determine if the read has finished?

Comment: Thanks, so i could use glClientWaitSync or glWaitSync instructions. Is my application client or server to the GL and what would i use as the sync parameter?

Answer (score 2):

To add on to Bahbar's answer:

- After `glReadPixels`, if you plan on reading back the data, I believe you should call `glMemoryBarrier(GL_PIXEL_BUFFER_BARRIER_BIT);`.
- After `glReadPixels` and `glMemoryBarrier`, you can create a Fence Sync with `glFenceSync(GL_SYNC_GPU_COMMANDS_COMPLETE, 0)`, then either check that the GPU has finished executing all instructions before the sync with `glGetSynciv(fence_sync, GL_SYNC_STATUS, sizeof(GLint), NULL, &result)`, or wait for GPU to finish executing all instructions before the sync with `glClientWaitSync(sync, GL_SYNC_FLUSH_COMMANDS_BIT, nanosecond_timeout)`.

Comment: For Unreal Engine 4, this is implemented in `FRHIGPUTextureReadback`.